# windows 8 incompatibility?

Tags: python, qt, windows-8, pyside, stackless

I cannot get my code to run on my win8 laptop. I am working with a combination of:

- Stackless Python 2.7.2
- Qt 4.8.4
- PySide 1.1.2
- Eclipse/Pydev and WingIDE

This works well on my Win7 PC, but now i have bought a demo laptop with windows 8. As far as I know all is installed the same way as on my PC.

When i run my program (same code) now, i get  a warning:

"Qt: Untested Windows version 6.2 detected!"

Ok, so that could be the source of my problem, but also i get errors:

- some times the program just quits after the warning above (i think only eclipse)
- sometimes i get an APPCRASH (i think only eclipse)
- sometimes i get the exception: TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases: mro() returned base with unsuitable layout ('')
- sometimes i get the exception: TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases: multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict

Especially the last two don't seem like a windows problem, but i don't see any other difference with my PC win7 install. Does anyone have any idea what is going on or how to fix this? Did i miss a step in the installation or is it some incompatibility maybe?

Cheers, Lars

Does anyone have some input on this?

Comment: try running the programs in Compatibility mode. By right click and properties,
Alternately look for the latest releases of the above Programs that can run on windows 8, Also note the bit version whether its 64 bit or 32 bit

Comment: doesn't Windows RT run on ARM processors? i.e. RISC architecture, i.e. there is reducet set of instructions on the processor itself, i.e. programs that work on Win7 don't have to work on Win8RT

Comment: i think i can only set compatibility options for the ide. I tried for WingIDE but that resulted in my code starting and stopping without error, output or warning at all (both winXP v3 and win7). I just saw that i can set compatibility for dll's, but i wouldn't know which one to change.

Comment: I am not using the RT version, just the PC version.

Comment: about microsoft; just cynical, wont slide to bitter ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Pyside 1.1.2 and Qt 4.8.4. The solution for me was to set the compatibility mode of the Python executable to Windows 7 via right click on the executable -> Properties -> Compatiblity -> Run this program in compatibility mode for: Windows 7

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Matthias, the link included is now a dead link.

Answer (score 0):

try using Hyper-V however Hyper-V is not installed by default in Windows 8. You need to go "Turn Windows features on or off."

Comment: hyper-v is not available on win8 (non-pro, which i have), why do you think this might be the solution?

Comment: i upgraded to pro (wanted to anyway) and installed hyper-v. still the same results. Do i need to do something with hyper-v? i dot get the relation between the erros and virtualisation.

Comment: Can you explain why you think that Hyper-V could be a solution to this problem?